# Sequences, Series and Cantor Set (show it is uncountable using series given) - Beginner level

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing, cantor-set

Let $(c_n)$ be a sequence with $c_i ∈ ${$0, 1$} for all $i$. The series from $n=0$ to infinity, $2c_n/3^{n+1}$. This series converges.

Now, for each $(c_n)$, the series is an element of $C$. I need to use this fact to show that $C$ is an uncountable set.

I have a general idea of what I'm expected to show but I'm not sure how to do it:

For each $(c_n)$, series with the terms $2c_n/3^{n+1}$ converge to different elements in the set $C$. And different starting sequences of $(c_n)$ make up different series so they lead to different convergence numbers in the set.

Here's my thoughts on the problem:

I need to prove that different starting sequences lead to different series. Then, I need to show that there are uncountably many such sequences. This will prove $C$ is an uncountable set.

So if I show there are uncountable many different sequences $(c_n)$, then I can show that there are uncountably many values the series can converge to in the set. So, the set is uncountable.

(I know there are a lot of cantor problems on here, but I'm having a hard time finding one that relates to my problem here. Many of the questions and posts are much more advanced compared to what I'm doing here, so I'm not really able to understand what is going on there. I'm not studying the cantor set, this is just a problem that uses it as context for an analysis problem on sequences and series.)

Comment: You don't need to show $(c_n)$ converges because you can find a sequence that doesn't. You probably meant to write the elements of cantor set in ternary numbers where $c \in \{0, 2\}$. This is uncountable by the cantor diagonal argument.

Comment: Also to prove the countability of sets, you show that there is back and forth injective function to set of natural numbers. For uncountability, you don't!

Comment: @SantoshLinkha this is the first time I've seen cantor sets, so I have to solve it in the context of the question using the $2c_n/3^{n+1}$ series. Where, for each $(c_n)$, the series is an element of $C$. I need to use this fact to show that $C$ is an uncountable set.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha So for uncountability, if I try to declare an injection from the function to $C$, I will get a contradiction? And that will show it must be uncountable?

Comment: You are writing $(c_i)$, by having index as integer, you are assuming that the set is countable. There is no need to define injection at all. Just define $c_i \mapsto i$. You are not going to get any contradiction this way. If you are into Cantor Sets, you mus tbe familiar with the concept of [cantor diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: @SantoshLinkha I don't really know. The $(c_i)$ was given as part of the question and the question asks me to show $C$ is uncountable.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha thanks for all the help so far. I worked on it a bit more and got some pointers. I put in bold what I need to do, but I'm having a hard time getting started there.

Comment: There have been many, many, many questions asked and answered concerning the Cantor set on this website. Chances are your question is among them. Please do a search for an earlier question that shows you how to answer yours.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand that there are many posts on Cantor set, but I have tried to find something similar to my question, but I haven't found a post that helps me figure something out yet. Also, I'm not studying cantor set, so many of the posts are beyond my understanding. I'm supposed to solve this using just sequences and series which I haven't yet found.